# Byte to 32-bit adress conversion

Tags: memory-address, quartus

In one of Intels IP Cores datasheet they do conversion from byte (0x17ff) to 32-bit (0x5ff) and I would like to know how they do that (from Parameter Editor Adress to Avalon-MM Address), an example would be great.

[image: Adresses]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a division by 0x100 (4), i.e. a bitshift to the right by two bits.

`0x1800 / 4 = 0x600`

`0x3000 / 4 = 0xC00`

Which makes sense, because 32 bits are four bytes. You'll see as well that there are four times as many byte addresses as there are 32-bit addresses for the same reason.

Comment: Yea I noticed the 4 times factor just wasnt convinced its that plane and simple.
Thank you good sir